# Should I use a subquery?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables, one that stores the current price, and one that stores the historical price of items.  I want to create a query that pulls the current price, and the difference between the current price and the most recent historical price.

In the historical table, I have the start and end times of the price, so I can just select the most recent price, but how do I pull it all together in one query?  Or do I have to do a subquery?

```
select p.current_price,
h.historical_price
h.historical_time  

from price p

inner join price_history h
on p.id = h.id
where max(h.historical_time)
```

This obviously doesn't work, but that is what I'm trying to accomplish.

This gives me the current and historical price.  But I want to make sure I have the most RECENT price.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this. Note, you may get duplicate records if there are two price entries with the same date for the same `id` in `price_history`:

```
select p.current_price, h.historical_price,
    p.current_price - h.historical_price as PriceDeff, h.historical_time 
from price p
inner join (
    select id, max(historical_time) as MaxHistoricalTime
    from price_history
    group by id
) hm on p.id = hm.id
inner join price_history h on hm.id = h.id 
    and hm.MaxHistoricalTime = h.historical_time
```

Comment: I might add, the dates are actually timestamps... so unless the prices are updated more than once a second I should be good for duplicates! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way of doing this without a subquery that isn't worse. On the other hand, if your table is indexed correctly, subqueries returning results of aggregate functions are generally pretty fast.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on the guy's answer above, but yes, it's important that aggregate function subqueries be queried on the same keys as the container function, or else you may get funny results when you have coincidental data that doesn't jive with your aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      p.current_price,
      h3.historical_price,
      h3.historical_time
  from 
      price p,
      ( select h1.id, max( h1.historical_time ) as MaxHT
            from price_history h1
            group by 1 ) h2,
      price_history h3
  where 
          p.id = h2.id
      and p.id = h3.id
      and h2.MaxHT = h3.historical_time
```